# Working with ObjectListVew

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, objectlistview

I am new to this control. I downloaded ObjectListView control from brightideassoftware. I am using the VS2010 / Visual basic.net.
I added it as a project, and one more project(testproj) to test it.
I also did reference the Control Project into testProj. I added the control to the form.
I get the following error :

Type 'BrightIdeasSoftware.TreeListView' is not defined.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy234eat.aspx

Comment: Thank you.. ObjectListView class library project is in .NET 2.0 version. My testproject was in .NET 4. i changed my testproject to .NET2. it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is now part of the ObjectListView FAQ, which can be found at:

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/faq.html

Hope this helps